# Issue in MS Access converting textboxes to combo boxes

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm experiencing a strange issue in MS Access in that when I convert a textbox to a combo box and save my database, the changes are not saved and the combo box changes back to a text box.

When I go to design view on the form, the combo box has reverted to a text box and hence my changes are not saved.

Can anyone help me understand why this is happening and how to stop it?

This is really frustrating as I need to use combo boxes for my fields but every time I change them, access just changes back to textboxes!

Thanks.

Comment: Are the warnings to save changes on?

Comment: Yes and it will prompt for me to save changes, to which I will click yes. And then when I go and recheck the form, the combo box has reverted again. Any ideas?

Comment: I will post tomorrow to confirm, but I believe this issue was caused by having some partial data saved on the form. I deleted all partially saved data, retried and the changes seemed to stick.

Comment: (not sure) Make a new access file then import all objects from old database to new database and see what happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update. It was because of partially saved data on the form. I removed the partial data and the comboboxes stayed permanently on the form and did not revert.